# xamarin ionic zip unzip causes error

Tags: android, zip, xamarin

I have the following method to unzip a file after download. But it ends with an error

> System.ArgumentException Path is empty at
>   System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory System.String path 0x00000 in file
>   unknown at ionic.zip.zipentry.internalExtract system.string basedir
>   system.io.stream outstream system.string password 0x00000 in filname
>   unknown.

The zip file does not have a password and can be opened e.g. with android zip

```
public void ExtractBilderZip()
{
    string documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    string unzipziel = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "Bilder");

    // if Bilder does not exist create subdirectory
    if (Directory.Exists(unzipziel)==false)
    {
        var directoryname = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "Bilder");
        Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryname);

    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    string zipToUnpack = localPathB;   //localPathB ist the zipFile name including path

    // I tried with and wihout the following 2 lines which makes no diffence
    zipToUnpack = zipToUnpack.Replace('/', Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
    unzipziel = unzipziel.Replace('/', Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);

    try
    {
        ZipFile zip1 = ZipFile.Read(zipToUnpack);

        zip1.ExtractAll(unzipziel,ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);       
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex1)
    {
        //System.Console.Error.WriteLine("exception: " + ex1);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "exception: " + ex1, ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by use of a Class called `ZipStorer` which I found by googleing. I found it here: [zipstorer.codeplex.com](http://zipstorer.codeplex.com) It is tiny and very easy to use!!

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(zipToUnpack);

FileStream inFile = fi.OpenRead();

// Get original file extension, 
// for example "doc" from report.doc.cmp.
string curFile = fi.FullName;
string origName = unzipziel;

try
{
    // Opens existing zip file
    ZipStorer zip = ZipStorer.Open(localPathB, FileAccess.Read);

    // Read all directory contents
    List<ZipStorer.ZipFileEntry> dir = zip.ReadCentralDir();

    // Extract all files in target directory
    string path;
    bool result;
    foreach (ZipStorer.ZipFileEntry entry in dir)
    {
        path = Path.Combine(unzipziel, Path.GetFileName(entry.FilenameInZip));
        result = zip.ExtractFile(entry, path);

        RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
            Button buttonUZ = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnUnzip);
            buttonUZ.Text = "Entpacke: " + entry.FilenameInZip;

        });
    }
    zip.Close();

    File.Delete(@localPathB);
}
catch (Exception ex1)
{
    var errorActivity = new Intent(this, typeof(ErrorActivity));
    errorActivity.PutExtra("ERROR", ex1.ToString());

    StartActivity(errorActivity);
}
```